# Django rest framework social oauth2 api url and response customization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-socialauth, django-oauth

I am making an API system which follows url like `localhost:8080/api/v1/end_name` and i'm using [django-rest-framework-social-oauth2](https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2) library for social authentication also for my custom user authentication. The problem is they are providing api response for url like `localhost:8080/auth/token` in following format e.g.

```
{
"access_token": "........",
"expires_in": 36000,
"token_type": "Bearer",
"scope": "read write",
"refresh_token": "......"
}
```

but i need to customize it in my way as my response format is different. My one is like following..

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "User created successfully",
    "data": {
        "email": "localtestuse2@beliefit.com"
    }
}
```

i need the response in my `data: {}`. My one question is

- How can I do it?

My another question is

- Can i customize the api url `localhost:8080/auth/token` to `localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/token`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i came up with the solution eventually. To make custom response, i had to override their method and customize the response according to my need. Here the method that is invoked named `TokenView`. so i customized it in following way

```
class UserLoginView(TokenView):
@method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters("password"))
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    url, headers, body, status = self.create_token_response(request)
    # body is str here, we need to make it proper json
    data = json.loads(body)

    if status != 200:
        response = Response(makeContext(True, "Couldn't generated token", data))
    else:
        response = Response(makeContext(False, "Token generated successfully", data))

    response.accepted_renderer = JSONRenderer()
    response.accepted_media_type = "application/json"
    response.renderer_context = {}
    return response
```

here `makecontext` is my customized json maker method.